# How to use fsockopen to check internet on/off and not stop for error?

Tags: php, fsockopen

I am simply trying to see if I have internet or not but fsockopen always returns an error when internet is down that stops my script.

I am using the following code in a function

```
$starttime = microtime(true);
$file      = @fsockopen ($domain, 80);
$stoptime  = microtime(true);
$status    = 0;

if (is_resource($file)) {
    fclose($file);
    $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
    $status = floor($status);
} else {
    $status = -1;  // site is down
}
return $status;
```

...called in a script that reload the page every 10 sec and save the status with a timestamp in a file.

I tried $domain = @"ip address".

How can I avoid fsockopen to stops for error and be able to test it instead?

Comment: When I try your code and either put in a fake domain or unplug my network connection, the `@` successfully suppresses any warnings for me?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you for testing on your side. If I put a fake ip address, I get Gateway "Timeout - The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application. Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at utopia.test Port 80".  If I disconnect the ethernet cable, it works fine but when the internet is down from the provider/router I get an error (I will send later when it is down again).